# Display Timer on Screen in Assembly MASM 8086

Tags: assembly, timer, masm, x86-16

I have to display the time passing on the screen, i've been looking online and found how to set up a time delay but i don't know how to display it on the screen 
Here's what i got right now(I dont even know if this is the way to do it)

```
 delay proc 

    mov ah, 00
    int 1Ah
    mov bx, dx
 jmp_delay:
    int 1Ah
    sub dx, bx
    cmp dl, delaytime                                                      
    jl jmp_delay    
    ret
 delay endp
```

Comment: That's not perfect delay procedure, it will somewhat work, but it will occasionally wait wrong amount of time. From the question it's not clear, what you want to display, there are other services than `int 1Ah` to get currently set DOS date/time, but if you want to create something like stopwatch, then [`int 1Ah`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_1a-0.html) is OK, it will allow you to measure with ~54ms accuracy (i.e. tenths of second, not hundredths). But you have to create a bit more complex logic to handle all possible return states.

Comment: thestrok3s, if any of the answers is useful, you can click its checkmark ✔ to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is a number and and you will need to convert it to string in order to display it. There are many procedures to do that, next I post one (procedure "dollars" is secondary but necessary) :

```
;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT A NUMBER IN STRING.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING (STR).
;PARAMETERS : AX = NUMBER TO CONVERT.
;             SI = POINTING WHERE TO STORE STRING.

proc number2string  
;FILL BUF WITH DOLLARS.
  push si
  call dollars
  pop  si

  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp

;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THE STRING WILL BE DISPLAYED.
;PARAMETER : SI = POINTING TO STRING TO FILL.

proc dollars                 
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  bl, '$'
  mov  [ si ], bl
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars

  ret
endp
```

With previous procedures you can display the time, next example shows how to use them, it also displays only seconds (I'm sure you will be able to display minutes and hours by yourself), notice there are two important variables that you will have to create in data segment :

```
seconds db ?         ;◄■■ IMPORTANT VARIABLES IN DATA SEGMENT.
buf     db 6 dup (?)


display_time:          
;▼ GET SYSTEM TIME.
  mov  ah, 2ch
  int  21h       ;◄■■ SECONDS RETURN IN DH. 
;▼ TIMER (1 SECOND).  
  cmp  dh, seconds
  je   display_time  ;◄■■ REPEAT UNTIL 1 SECOND PASSED.
  mov  seconds, dh
;▼ CONVERT SECONDS TO STRING.  
  xor  ax, ax  ;◄■■ NUMBER TO CONVERT TO STRING.
  mov  al, dh  ;◄■■ SECONDS IN AX.
  lea  si, buf  ;◄■■ VARIABLE WHERE STRING WILL BE STORED.
  call number2string  ;◄■■ CALL PROCEDURE THAT CONVERTS NUMBER TO STRING.
;▼ MOVE CURSOR TO 0,0.
  mov  dl, 0  ;◄■■ X.
  mov  dh, 0  ;◄■■ Y.
  mov  ah, 2
  mov  bh, 0
  int  10h  
;▼ DISPLAY STRING.
  mov  ah, 9
  lea  dx, buf
  int  21h
  jmp  display_time
```

Answer (score 0):

There could use several methods for this:

- Use the DOS int 21h to display text (maybe function 9?).
- Use the BIOS int 10h to display characters.
- Or finally write directly to the screen at B800:0000

Personally I'd use the BIOS method.